# pandas split string and extract upto n index position

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have my input data like as below stored in a dataframe column

```
active_days_revenue
active_days_rate
total_revenue
gap_days_rate
```

I would like to do the below

a) split the string using `_` delimiter

b) extract `n` elements from the delimiter

So, I tried the below

```
df['text'].split('_')[:1]  # but this doesn't work
df['text'].split('_')[0] # this works but returns only the 1st element
```

I expect my output like below. Instead of just getting items based on `0 index position`, I would like to get from `0 to 1st index position`

```
active_days
active_days
total_revenue
gap_days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a dynamic regex (fastest):

```
N = 2
df['out'] = df['text'].str.extract(fr'([^_]+(?:_[^_]+){{,{N-1}}})', expand=False)
```

Or slicing and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

```
df['out'] = df['text'].str.split('_').str[:2].agg('_'.join)
```

Or [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['out'] = df['text'].str.extractall('([^_]+)')[0].groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: '_'.join(x.head(2)))
```

Output:

```
                  text            out
0  active_days_revenue    active_days
1     active_days_rate    active_days
2        total_revenue  total_revenue
3        gap_days_rate       gap_days
```

##### timings

On 4k rows:

```
# extract
2.17 ms ± 431 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# split/slice/agg
3.56 ms ± 811 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# extractall
361 ms ± 30.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

###### using as grouper for columns

```
import re
N = 2
df1.groupby(lambda x: m.group() if (m:=re.match(fr'([^_]+(?:_[^_]+){{,{N-1}}})', x)) else x, axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: but one small issue. I am trying to use this code in another program of mine which has the below line `(df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1, sort=False)`. Here, am trying to replace the `x.split(_)` part with your code. but it threw error

Comment: The error is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`. can help me on this?

Comment: When I try dynamic regex option, I get another error which is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract'`

Comment: @TheGreat the use case you describe doesn't match your original question, you're grouping on `axis=1` here. This should be a different question with a clear example

Comment: Yeah, but I thought the solution will be kind of generalizable as it is difficult to reproduce the sample data for actual scenario

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the DataFrame/Series/Index methods are not always working the same way

Comment: You need to use python string methods for your use-case, see my update